# How to write an Rspec controller test with authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, controller, rspec-rails

I have two models:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
# app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

I am trying to test my `TeamsController` using [Rspec](http://rspec.info/) and [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails).

Before I can create a new Team I need an authenticated User.

I created a :user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name   "John"
    last_name    "Doe"
    email        {|n| "email#{n}@email.com" }
    mobile_phone "1235551234"
    company_name "Widgets Inc."
    password     "password"
  end
end
```

Here are the relevant parts of `teams_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TeamsController, type: :controller do

  # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
  # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
  # TeamsController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "assigns all teams as @teams" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

      team = Team.create!(name: "New Team Name", user: user)

      get :index, {}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:teams)).to eq([team])
    end
  end
end
```

The test is failing:

```
1) TeamsController GET #index assigns all teams as @teams
     Failure/Error: get :index, {}, valid_session
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand how I need to populate `:valid_session` so that the test will pass. I thought I'd have to explicitly call an authenticate method but that might not be true. I'm trying to test the Team controller... not User authentication.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show where you require the user to be authenticated when creating a team? Did you have a look at [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec))?

Comment: If you are not using devise you can see my sol'n here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881504/rspec-controller-specs-fail-after-adding-authorization-to-rails4-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this in your rails_helper:

```
module ControllerMacros    
  def sign_me_in
    before :each do
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in :user, @current_user
    end 
  end 
end

Rspec.configure do |config|
    #other rspec stuff
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
    config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
 end
```

Then in your controller spec, (provided you're requiring your rails_helper) you can just to `sign_me_in` whenever you want to be signed in and not bother about the valid_session:

```
RSpec.describe TeamsController, type: :controller do
  sign_me_in
  #etc...
end
```

However in your specific case you want to know who you're signed in as, so you can do  this:

```
RSpec.describe TeamsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "assigns all teams as @teams" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      team = Team.create!(name: "New Team Name", user: user)
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in :user, user
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:teams)).to eq([team])
    end
  end
end
```

The devise mappings line may not be required in your case, but can't say without inspecting your full app.

Comment: This is great @Yule - thanks! When I run the `GET #Index` test the way you wrote it I see this failure: https://goo.gl/6307Ke Where does `sign_in` come from?

Comment: Apologies, missed an RSpec config. Edited answer: `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller` in your rails_helper

Comment: `Devise::TestHelpers` is deprecated. Use `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` instead